# Apache - Multiple AuthLDAPURL

Tags: apache-2.2, active-directory, ldap, virtualhost

I currently have my vhosts setup to authenticate via LDAPS via Apache reverse proxy
.
I am wondering if it's possible to add a backup/fallback LDAP server if my primary one goes down.

I tried working with AuthnProviderAlias after enabling mod authn_alias but I get the error when restarting apache.

```
AuthnProviderAlias not allowed here
```

Example of my [vhost config](http://pastebin.com/mcXt2pAZ).

Any ideas?

Comment: Not so sure about this, but I would setup an LDAP cluster with floating IP and live master-master replication. That should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work. It's actually really simple. Just put the two LDAP servers in the same string:

```
AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://dc01.xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx dc02.xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx/xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx?saMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
```